# Lining style of cfr-lm with text of amsmath

Tags: amsmath, cfr-lm

I try to combine the lining style of `cfr-lm` with the `\text` macro of `amsmath`.
But I get only error messages.
When I use the `nfssext-cfr` package that defines the `\lstyle`, macro everything is fine.
The same holds true if I replace the `\text` macro with the `\mbox` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
% \usepackage{nfssext-cfr} % <- works
\usepackage{cfr-lm}

\begin{document}
% $\mbox{\lstyle 123}$ % <- works
$\text{\lstyle 123}$
\end{document}
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: Note that, if you have the option of using the OpenType font, `fontspec` supports `\liningnums`.

Comment: @Davislor That is true, but unfortunately some of my collaborators are still not convinced that pdflatex has significant advantage over latex. I would not be able to make them switch to lualatex.

Comment: @barbarabeeton The package can be found at https://ctan.org/pkg/cfr-lm in texlive it is package under fonts-extra.

Comment: @JanHajer Better not tell them that `latex` has been a symlink to `pdflatex` for years?

Comment: The problem appears to be an incompatibility with `cfr-lm`.  This has been confirmed on the chat by two others very knowledgeable about the internals of `amsmath`.  I tried to debug it, but ran into an impasse after several hours.  The incompatibility appears to be in a definition in a package loaded by `cfr-lm`, not directly in that package.